# Cabal error: invalid preprocessing directive #-}

Tags: haskell, gcc, cabal, haskell-platform

```
$ cabal install arithmoi-0.4.0.3
```

results in multiple errors like:

```
Math/NumberTheory/Moduli.hs:489:4:
     error: invalid preprocessing directive
      #-}
       ^
```

### My System:

OSX Mavericks

Cabal version = 1.18.1.1

GHCI version = 7.6.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible workaround [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1ml97r/haskellcafe_psa_do_not_install_xcode_5_if_you_are/ccajlbj).

`xCode 5` comes with `clang` as c/c++/obj-c compiler. `Haskell Platform` is not ready for that. The next `ghc` release will fix that.

Also see [here](https://gist.github.com/cartazio/7131371).

Comment: Perfect, this worked for me:

Intall CLI tool, then
https://gist.github.com/cartazio/7131371#comment-936057

Comment: Tried the [clang wrapper](https://github.com/ghc-ios/ghc-ios-scripts/blob/master/clang-xcode5-wrapper.hs), it works just great!