# Can not install 'cabal-install' on mac os

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use cabal on Mac OS, but when I run 'cabal install cabal-install' the system hang over.

```
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install

$ cabal install cabal-install
```

...

```
[70 of 70] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/q8/sxlwx4b16gg9gm7xgxr9lc2w0000gn/T/Cabal-1.18.1.3-51346/Cabal-1.18.1.3/Setup.hs, /var/folders/q8/sxlwx4b16gg9gm7xgxr9lc2w0000gn/T/Cabal-1.18.1.3-51346/Cabal-1.18.1.3/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/q8/sxlwx4b16gg9gm7xgxr9lc2w0000gn/T/Cabal-1.18.1.3-51346/Cabal-1.18.1.3/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring Cabal-1.18.1.3...
```

This is last message I have got.  After this line the system hang over for more than hour.

After Ctrl+C I have got:

```
^Csetup: The program ghc version >=6.4 is required but the version of
/usr/bin/ghc could not be determined.
```

I am just wondering if there is a problem here and how can I fix it ?

Comment: What version of GHC do you have?  Can you verify that manually?

Comment: $ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.2

Comment: Someone else had the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659929/cabal-cant-determine-ghc-version).  The solution was to reinstall the haskell platform using Homebrew, so not really a fix so much as a workaround.

Comment: What happens if you do `$ ghc --numeric-version`?  That's the command that Cabal uses to try to get the version number for GHC.

Comment: $ ghc --numeric-version
7.4.2

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have a Mac, so I don't know if I can really help you much more.  It seems like everything should be working just fine.  You could try running it with a higher verbosity to see if it prints out any more clues.

Comment: Open GHCi, run `:m Distribution.Simple.Program Distribution.Verbosity`, then `findProgramVersion "--numeric-version" id deafening "/usr/bin/ghc"`.  What do you get?

Comment: /usr/bin/ghc is version 7.4.2
Just (Version {versionBranch = [7,4,2], versionTags = []})

Comment: That's very odd, it can get the version properly there, but not when actually running `cabal`.  Sounds like it might be a path or configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I have installed cabal-install using brew (as you recommended earlier).  But now I have this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597324/cabal-error-invalid-preprocessing-directive.  Looks like it is not easy to install haskell/cabal on Mac OS :)